React App Behaves Differently on Web and Android WebView: Login Modal vs. HTTP 500 Error
I have a React app deployed on Google, and I recently exported a bundled version of it into an Android app using Android Studio. When I open the app on my phone and navigate to a specific tab (where login is required), I observe inconsistent behavior compared to the web version:
Web Version: If I'm not logged in, a login modal pops up as expected.
Android App/WebView: Instead of the modal, I get an HTTP 500 error.
I connected my phone to the IDE (Android Studio) to monitor network/API calls but could not successfully capture them.
On the Android app/WebView, I expect the login modal to appear (just like it does on the web) if I’m not logged in, instead of throwing a 500 error.
